# AX2009 manual NumSeq on business relation?

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Anyone know why the number sequence on business relation (AX 2009) should not be manual, according to basic code?

Table method smmBusRelTable.checkNumberSequence()

```
if (numberSequenceReference)
{
    numberseq = NumberSequenceTable::find(numberSequenceReference.NumberSequence);

    if (numberseq)
    {
        if (numberseq.Manual)
        {
            // Business relation number sequence must not be manual
            ret = checkFailed("@SYS81360");
        }
    }
  ...
```

Manual can be used, but of course the warning "Business relation number sequence must not be manual" will pop up everytime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is it was written in some spec, that prospects should have an automatic number sequence.

Also AX users rarely cares about the number of a prospect, but may care about the number of the customer, maybe using phone numbers or something else. Prospect are usually imported from external sources and there may be 10 or 1000 more prospects than customers.

Comment: Yeah, probably. I traced the actual problem to CustTable.update(), where code was changed from
if (_updateSmmBusRelTable)
{
    smmBusRelTable::updateFromCustTableSFA2(this, '', false);
}
to
if (_updateSmmBusRelTable)
{
    smmBusRelTable::updateFromCustTableSFA2(this);
}

And without that false, the numseq manual check is run down the road.